# Change baseUrl on Angular-CLI e2e protractor test

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

I would like to run my angular e2e test against a running server. The default URL is configured in the `protractor.conf.js` file but it seems like there is no command line argument which allow to override it at runtime. I tried using the option `--public-host` but it does not work. Is there any solution other than override the `protractor.conf.js` file?

Answer (score 3):

With angular 6 the only command which works is this

```
ng e2e --dev-server-target="" --base-url="https://localhost:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass command line arguments, I never worked with Angular CLI, but what you can normally do is add this behind the script you are running `ng e2e --baseUrl=http://your.other.url.com`, it could be that Angular CLI needs a double `--` so it becomes `ng e2e -- --baseUrl=http://your.other.url.com`. The double `--` could be needed to tell that command line arguments are passed. 
You don't need to do that if you have multiple command line arguments, only add it once, if Angular CLI needs it. I normally use it when I have a npm script.

Good luck

Comment: It does not seem to work. I ran the following command `ng e2e --server false -- --baseUrl=http://your.other.url.com` and the browser still tries to connect to the baseUrl specified in the `protractor.conf.js` instead.

Comment: I also tried that options before and it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the latest version of @angular/cli released yesterday 
([see changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.2.0)) is resolving the issue to override the baseUrl. However, it does not work when combined with the option `--serve false`.

Comment: As you see in the change log you would need to provide the parameter `--publicHost`. Did you also try this?

Answer (score -1):

Passing `--no-serve` and `--base-href=http://yoururltotest:8080` will not build as well as serve the passed base url in `--base-href=` from the command.

I tried other combinations of/with options but did not work.

so the command will be

```
ng e2e --no-serve --base-href=https://yoururltotest:8888
```